# how to get the attribute value inside cdata from the response and use it in other request

Tags: groovy, soapui, cdata

1. This is my response, how to get `HIndex` attribute value?

   ```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
       <HResponse xmlns="http://demo.org/">
           <HResult>
               <![CDATA[
               <HRS>
                   <Header>
                       <Currency>INR</Currency>
                       <SessionId>1313123123123123123</SessionId>
                   </Header>
                   <HotelDetails>
                       <Stay></Stay>
                       <Hotel HIndex="1701"  PrefContract="" HDIndex="28">
                           <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                           <HImg>demo</HImg>
                       </Hotel>
                      <Hotel HIndex="1702"  PrefContract="" HDIndex="29">
                           <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                           <HImg>demo</HImg>
                       </Hotel>
                       <Hotel HIndex="1703" PrefContract="" HDIndex="30">
                           <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                           <HImg>demo</HImg>
                       </Hotel>
                 </HotelDetails>
               </HRS>
             ]]>
           </HResult>
       </HResponse>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
   ```
2. I want to use `HIndex` value in the other request.Am able to select the other node value. But, when I am selecting attribute, I am getting the `null` value

Comment: Here there are multiple `HIndex` in the response. Do you want the list of values?

Comment: no i wanto select only one index

Comment: Hi Rao I understood ur previous example for extracting parameter well and applied it. pls help me in getting  the attribute value.

Comment: @albciff has provided the solution already, not exactly sure the latest on this. An attribute can be fetched using `.@attribute`. By the way, do you know `HIndex` value before? so that it can be searched ? or you want the first `HIndex` always irrespective of their order of presence in the data? or all of them in a list? please clarify the question for the requested info, and used edit option to update the question.

Comment: You also mentioned `1701` for first request, next value for another request etc. Do you mean, you need send multiple following requests based on the `HIndex` count of the previous step response?

Comment: @Rao i hava updated the question

Comment: Hmm.. could not see much changes in the question addressing my earlier comments. Please go thru comments again and clarify.

Comment: ya am sry. i dono the HIndex value before as am receiving the response dynamically.

Comment: Ok, how about other clarifications requested?

Comment: no I dont wanto send the multiple request based on HIndex count . all i need is, wanto get any one of the HIndex attribute value and use it in another response

Comment: Added my answer, please see if that helps. Of course, not much different from @albciff.

Comment: @Rao I think that the problem is that the OP doesn't try to understand what is he doing, probably with your answer he can make it work since `context.response` in the script assertion is what he is looking for (see the comments on my answer but he didn't try to understand even `getTestStepByName` method :) ). May the force be with you my friend :)!

Comment: @albciff, I saw long comments on your answer. And the info available in the question wasn't concrete or inadequate. And you are awesome, amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `Script Assertion` for the first request step. This will avoid additional groovy script step in the test case.

Please follow the appropriate comments in-line:

```
/**
 * This is Script Assertion for the first
 * request step which extracts cdata from response,
 * then HIndex'es from extracted cdata. And
 * Assigns first value at test case level, so that
 * it can be used in the rest of the test steps of
 * the same test case.
 * */

/**
* Closure to parse and retrieve the data
* retrieves element or attribute
*/
def searchData = { data, item, itemType ->
    def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
    if ('attribute' == itemType) {
        return parsedData?.'**'.findAll{it.@"$item".text()}*.@"$item"
    }
    parsedData?.'**'.find { it.name() == item} as String
}

//Assert response xml
assert context.response, "Response data is empty or null"

//Get the CDATA from response which is inside of HResult
def cData = searchData(context.response, 'HResult', 'element')

//Assert retrieved CDATA is not empty
assert cData, "Data inside of HResult is empty or null"

//Get the HIndex list
def hIndexes = searchData(cData, 'HIndex', 'attribute')

//Print list of hIndexes
log.info hIndexes

//Print the first in the list
log.info "First HIndex is : ${hIndexes?.first()}"

//Print the last in the list
log.info "Last HIndex is : ${hIndexes?.last()}"

//Use the required HIndex from the list
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('HINDEX', hIndexes?.first().toString())
//or the below one using index
//context.testCase.setPropertyValue('HINDEX', hIndexes[0]?.toString())
```

In the following test steps, you can use the saved `HINDEX` in the following ways:

- If the following step is request step (REST, SOAP, HTTP, JDBC etc), then use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) `${#TestCase#HINDEX}` like `<Index>${#TestCase#HINDEX}</Index>`
- If the following step is groovy script, then use one of the below:
  `context.expand('${#TestCase#HINDEX}')` or
  `context.testCase.getPropertyValue('HINDEX')` or
  `testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('HINDEX')`

You can quickly try & execute the script from [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5080675459792896).

Comment: ur awesome .Thanks wont be the right thing for your great tollerence and effort. Its running fine

Comment: Glad to know that the answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *Groovy script testStep*, to parse your SOAP testStep response. More exactly use [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to parse your response, get the `CDATA` finding in the slurper by tag name, and parse the `CDATA` again due that `XmlSlurper` returns `CDATA` as `String`. Finally find your desired node by its name and then access its attribute value using `node.@attributeName` notation. Something like this must works for your case:

```
def xml = '''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <HResponse xmlns="http://demo.org/">
        <HResult>
            <![CDATA[
            <HRS>
                <Header>
                    <Currency>INR</Currency>
                    <SessionId>1313123123123123123</SessionId>
                </Header>
                <HotelDetails>
                    <Stay></Stay>
                    <Hotel HIndex="1701"  PrefContract="" HDIndex="28">
                        <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                        <HImg>demo</HImg>
                    </Hotel>
                   <Hotel HIndex="1702"  PrefContract="" HDIndex="29">
                        <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                        <HImg>demo</HImg>
                    </Hotel>
                    <Hotel HIndex="1703" PrefContract="" HDIndex="30">
                        <HNm> Demo</HNm>
                        <HImg>demo</HImg>
                    </Hotel>
              </HotelDetails>
            </HRS>
          ]]>
        </HResult>
    </HResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def cdataAsStr = slurper.'**'.find { it.name() == 'HResult' }.toString()
def cdataSlurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(cdataAsStr)
// get all HIndex attribute values from `<Hotel>`
def hIndexValues = cdataSlurper.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Hotel' }*.@HIndex as List
```

**Notes**:

- In your question the Xml inside `CDATA` is not well formed, use `<Stay></Stay>` instead of `<Stay></stay>` (note the lower case).
- If your are interested only in the attribute value from the first `<Hotel>` then access the first element from the list as: `hIndexValues[0]`.
- If instead of a `String` as in the example you want to get the Xml content from a SOAP testStep use: 
  `testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('TestStepName').getPropertyValue('response')` to define the `def xml` object.
- To use the attribute values in other testSteps save it at some level (for example testCase `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('myAttrValue',hIndexValues[0].toString())`) an then use the [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) notation inside other testStep request `${#TestCase#myAttrValue}`.

If you want to use the above script in the *Script Assertion* instead of in the *Groovy testStep* you can use the same script as above only changing the way you get the response Xml from you testStep:

```
// in the script assertion you can access the
// response from the current testStep simply with
// messageExchange.getResponseContent()
def xml = messageExchange.getResponseContent()
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def cdataAsStr = slurper.'**'.find { it.name() == 'HResult' }.toString()
def cdataSlurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(cdataAsStr)
// get all HIndex attribute values from `<Hotel>`
def hIndexValues = cdataSlurper.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Hotel' }*.@HIndex as List
```

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property:xml for class:error at line 2

Comment: @vikkiwiggi I think that you don't copy the example correclty... make sure that there is `def xml` assigned to some value in your script. If not then `new XmlSurper().parseText(xml)` will throw this error, since `xml` it's not declared.

Comment: testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('TestStepName').getPropertyValue('response') if am using the above property  am getting the error like content is not allowed in prolog

Comment: @vikkiwiggi content is not allowed in prolog is thrown when there is a problem parsing a string to convert it to xml... This is normally due some invalid character in your response xml, or problems with the charset encoding. Check that your response is correct and doesn't have any encoding problems, you can also check the content-type http-header...

Comment: can we do using assertion script . while using assertion script am getting the node values but i couldnt able to access the attribute

Comment: @vikkiwiggi The code to get the attribute must work the same way in both places: in the script assertion and in groovy script testStep. Are you sure that your response is actually the same that the xml you post in the question? The only difference is that in the script assertion instead of `testRunner` you must use `context`.

Comment: yes my response in correct, pls can u give the example without using the def xml in the response, pls provide some steps while doing it through assertion method

Comment: meanwhile while trying like wt u said i got the error code: cannot invoke method getPropertyvalue() on null object

Comment: @vikkiwiggi You receive `cannot invoke method getPropertyvalue() on null` because you don't use the correct name of your testStep response. This method is selfexplanatory `getTestStepByName('TestStepName')`, I use `'TestStepName'` to explain the behavior  but you've to use your testStep name.

Comment: vikkiwiggi You've all the necessary information to get the attribute value for your xml, please take the time to understand it, read the documentation and the api if needed. Then if you've more doubts provide the necessary details and explain exactly what are you trying. Anywise probably @Rao provides the answer you want so take a look on it, but please follow my advise before asking it for a clarification again.

Comment: I need to understand a lot . Thanks for ur effort. I'll be improvising .